# Screen Flickering after windows update, despite display driver reinstall

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, display, display-driver

Usually I try an hour or two of my google-fu before I go asking for help, but my case is a bit strange and it's starting to scare me a bit.

After a recent windows update (If it were possible, I'd stop them from ever happening, ever) my screen started periodically flickering (one second of black, then back to normal). After a reboot though, it got more intense (instead of 2-5 mins between flickers, they were happening every minute). Decided to see if there's an Nvidia updated driver (have a GTX 1060) and I installed it. Thing is, the flickering during the install (this was a fresh boot, so maybe not the installer's fault) got to once every 2 seconds. Towards the end of the install, I got a black screen and a message from my Sony TV about "Unsupported Signal" or something similar.

After the update and a fresh boot, everything looked ok, but the flash was still happening every 5-10 minutes. I decided to completely remove the driver from control panel, reboot, install a fresh driver, but alas, still flashing every 5-10 minutes.

I thought that maybe it's the integrated driver or something, so I stopped it from my bios settings, it's no longer visible in device manager, and I reinstalled the display driver once more. It still hasn't gone away.
At this point I'm shitting my pants that it's my GPU, which is brand new, but

I'm afraid I have misplaced my warranty note.

EDIT: It's strange, sometimes (maybe alt tab out of game related) it increases frequency.

Comment: It sounds like a problem with the cable. Have you tried to unplug it at both ends, then reseat it? and if that doesn't work, replace the cable? Also, does it happen with a different screen?

Comment: @LPChip I will try that in a second, but first I decided to find a tool (DDU) to remove all traces of display drivers (including registry and temp files). During this time in which I had no drivers runnign, the screen did not flicker.

Comment: Without drivers, the screen is under a lower bandwidth and might not have a problem with interference that can happen with a faulty cable. But it may be a driver issue too or a problem with the GPU.

Comment: @LPChip Any other tips on troubleshooting? I have done the cleanest possible driver install without wiping everything. No flickers as of yet, but that's not conclusive. During install, the screen flickered like crazy (it's normal for screen to go black, but that was not what was happening). I can't replace the cable today, so the only other thing I can inspect is the video card, but I don't know what to try. Power is sufficient, everything is connected, the card is well slotted.

Comment: @LPChip You may be right, I just remembered I had a second monitor back home and I just happened to bring the spare cable with me. No more flickering, for now. Will close this tomorrow if it's fixed.

Comment: I've posted an answer, if it indeed is the cable, just mark it as solved. Others may benefit from this question as well. :)

Comment: I have had the same flickering problem on some NVIDIA cards, I tried rebooting and nothing, then I booted using my Linux (Fedora) drive and installed the drivers and everything worked as expected, so it could also be a problem with Windows (I was using an HDMI to DVI-D though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like this could be the cable.

Try taking off the cable and reseat, or even better, try to swap it for a different cable.